# Call a Web Service reference Request in C#

Tags: c#, web-services, testing

I am currently trying to figure out how to setup some testing for web services in C#.

I have referenced the web services in my project and have populated the request, I am just wondering how I can call the request method?

Below is the existing code, and I am trying to simulate using the AddNewResponder web service.  All of the items that the web service asks for are populated below, I just can't seem to figure out how to execute the web service code.

```
        static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int testID = 0;

        //populate the test user with user data
        TestUser tUser = GetUserData(testID);           

        //Create Request Body
        RCWS.AddNewResponderRequestBody respRequestBody = new RCWS.AddNewResponderRequestBody();

        respRequestBody.PriorityCode = tUser.PriCode;
        respRequestBody.ClientCode = "TestData";
        respRequestBody.Domain = "TestDomain";
        respRequestBody.IPAddress = "192.168.2.1";
        respRequestBody.Source = "web";
        respRequestBody.OS = "WinNT";
        respRequestBody.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/28.0.1500.95 Safari/537.36";
        respRequestBody.Browser = "Chrome";

        //Create Request
        RCWS.AddNewResponderRequest addNewResp = new RCWS.AddNewResponderRequest(respRequestBody);

    }
```

Comment: Some more information on what I am trying to do.  I have added a Service Reference to my project which links to the WSDL for the web services that we use.  I am trying to process a Request for one of the services (AddNewResponder) and receive a Response.

Then I want to parse the response so that I can check to be sure I got what I was expecting...  Thanks.

Comment: You don't have to parse the response. The response is already in `addNewResp`.

Comment: Ok how do I get the Response out then?

Comment: `addNewResp` _is_ the response.

Comment: Been shooting from the hip, I found his interface and am now able to get the responses.